# How to test Rails belongs_to relationship using rspec integration test and factory girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara, factory-bot

Still trying to get my head around relationships and testing in rails/rspec.

I have an app that has a model Quizzes which belongs_to an Icon model, and that has_many quizzes.

I'm trying to test that a new quiz is created on the quiz/new page using rspec/capybara and factory girl to create my data in the tests.

Here is my test as it is..

```
 describe "new quiz page" do

    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    let(:icon) { FactoryGirl.create(:icon) }

    before do
        sign_in user
        visit new_quiz_path
    end 

    ....

    describe "with valid info" do
      before do
        fill_in "Title",         with: "Example title"
        fill_in "Description",  with: "Example quiz description"
        select icon.title,              from: "quiz_icon_id"
      end

      it "should create new content" do
        expect { click_button submit }.to change(Quiz, :count).by(1)
      end
    end
end
```

The rspec error I'm getting is...

```
     Failure/Error: select icon.title,              from: "quiz_icon_id"
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   cannot select option, no option with text 'Icon 1' in select box 'quiz_icon_id'
```

So the problem obviously is that there are no icons to select from. One is definitely being created with the factory girl method as it can find the title but is not replicated in the test form. I can't get my head around how to get this to work.

Can anyone offer some pointers here?

Thanks, Mark.

Comment: In your `it` block put `save_and_open_page` to see the page that's being rendered.

Comment: What does your form input look like for the "quiz_icon_id"? In general you should be using the label of the field to select from. Eg if a field was called `category` but on the form the label was called `User Category` then you need to use `from: "User Category".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Dty for save_and_open_page tip. That helped me debug the problem.

The icon wasn't being created, or at least wasn't there when the test was being run on the page.

To solve I did this instead of the let(:icon) statement.

```
before(:all) { 1.times {  FactoryGirl.create(:icon) } }
after(:all) { Icon.delete_all }
```

Then when the tests filled in the form I used Icon.first.title.

```
before do
   fill_in "Title",         with: "Example title"
   fill_in "Description",  with: "Example quiz description"
   select Icon.first.title,         from: "quiz_icon_id"
end
```

I don't really understand why I had to use a before(:all) statement for the Icons to be created rather than the 'let' statement I had previously though. If anyone can suggest why this is the case that would be appreciated.

Comment: `let` is lazy-evaluated. When the example reaches `visit`, the icon needs have been created already -- it hasn't, because the `let` is not evaluated until `icon` is referenced (in the second before block of your code). You can fix this by moving it into an earlier before block, or by using `let!`, which is evaluated immediately.